# Im having problem building docker for golang api

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm new to docker.

I'm trying to implement RESTfull api in go using echo server. My code works fine when I run `main.go` but i cant run it using docker.

this is my echo server:

```
r := router.Router()
r.Logger.Fatal(r.Start("localhost:8080"))
```

and this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest AS build

ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=1

#Maintainer info
LABEL maintainer="Saman Hoseini"

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o main .

#this step is for CGO libraries
RUN ldd main | tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | grep '^/' | \
    xargs -I % sh -c 'mkdir -p $(dirname ./%); cp % ./%;'
RUN mkdir -p lib64 && cp /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 lib64/

#Second stage of build
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk --no-cache add ca-certificates \
    sqlite

COPY --from=build /app ./

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

After build when i run the container i face curl failure:

> $ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 my-docker
>
> $ curl http://localhost:8080
>
> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Don't bind to localhost:8080, use :8080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run your application on the external port of your container.

```
r := router.Router()
r.Logger.Fatal(r.Start(":8080"))
```

This happens because the `EXPOSE 8080` command forwards the application port open on the external port of the container (not internal, like localhost).

After this, command `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 my-docker`, more precisely a parameter `-p`, forwards external port from your container to external port on your machine.